# Does anyone know what this mean? -----> sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown command: `.'

Tags: linux

```
\#Add another new line of text to hosts and send the output to       

hosts_update.sh
sed '/localhost/a\

# Gateway
10.0.0.1    it20.it.cs.umb.edu  it20

# Addresses for the Windows PCs
10.0.0.240  it21.it.cs.umb.edu it21\
10.0.0.241  it22.it.cs.umb.edu it22\
10.0.0.242  it23.it.cs.umb.edu it23\
10.0.0.243  it24.it.cs.umb.edu it24\
10.0.0.244  it25.it.cs.umb.edu it25\
10.0.0.245  it26.it.cs.umb.edu it26\
10.0.0.246  it27.it.cs.umb.edu it27\
10.0.0.247  it28.it.cs.umb.edu it28\
' hosts > hosts_update.sh
```

Comment: Please explain your question in greater detail.

Comment: if you are using the continuation char on the `# Addresses ...` block, why  aren't you using it for all the lines after the initial append command (i.e.` /localhost/a\? Good luck.

Comment: It's telling you that it doesn't understand the command `.`.  You are telling sed to append a blank line after any line that matches `localhost`, then there is a comment, and then you want to execute the command `.0.0.1` on line 10.  But sed doesn't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your initial couple of lines look way off for a shell script. It looks like your `hosts_update.sh` line should be part of the comments (and the comment shouldn't start with a `\` anyway):

```
# Add another new line of text to hosts and send the output
#   to hosts_update.sh
```

Secondly, you need a `\` at the end of *each* line that you're appending with `sed`, at the moment you only have it on certain select lines. With that in mind, this script is probably what you wanted:

```
# Add another new line of text to hosts and send the output
#   to hosts_update.sh

sed '/localhost/a\
\
# Gateway\
10.0.0.1    it20.it.cs.umb.edu  it20\
\
# Addresses for the Windows PCs\
10.0.0.240  it21.it.cs.umb.edu it21\
10.0.0.241  it22.it.cs.umb.edu it22\
10.0.0.242  it23.it.cs.umb.edu it23\
10.0.0.243  it24.it.cs.umb.edu it24\
10.0.0.244  it25.it.cs.umb.edu it25\
10.0.0.245  it26.it.cs.umb.edu it26\
10.0.0.246  it27.it.cs.umb.edu it27\
10.0.0.247  it28.it.cs.umb.edu it28\
' hosts > hosts_update.sh
```

What's actually happening in your case (without the `\` continuation characters):

```
sed '/localhost/a\

# Gateway
10.0.0.1    it20.it.cs.umb.edu  it20
```

is that:

- you append a single blank line after `localhost`;
- then you have a `sed` comment line;
- then you tell `sed` to execute `.` on line number ten.

At that point, `sed` rightly complains it has no idea what to do with the `.` command :-)

I'd say, based on experience, an earlier (working) iteration of the script had only the `it21-28` lines and someone added (badly) the `it20` and comment/blank lines. That's based on the fact only those lines are the errant ones. However, that's just (informed) speculation and doesn't affect the answer.

And, finally, you probably *don't* want to call the resultant file `hosts_update.sh`, people will almost certainly think it's a shell script rather than the hosts file it *actually* is.